# Reuse data with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I need to reuse data in my app with hook, so I created a hook called `useData`

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useData() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("error");

  return [{ message, type }, { setMessage, setType }];
}
```

And then I use my hook in my app like below.

```js
function App() {
  const [data, action] = useData();

  const handleClick = () => {
    action.setMessage("Hello message");
    action.setType("info");

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Alert Data
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I clicked the button `Alert Data` at the first time it will alert

```
{message: "", type: "error"}
```

My expectation is

```
{message: "Hello message", type: "info"}
```

What am I doing it wrong here? Please let me know, and is there any way to fix this code?

Here's the codesandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-hugle-zm2e2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React.js, setState isn't a synchronous function. That is, setState doesn't change the state instantly. For this case, setState has a version with the completion callback. You can define a custom Hook with the completion callback. Fortunately, there is an npm package called "use-state-with-callback".

Or you can write the code as follows.

useData.js

```js
export default function useData(msg, cb) {
  
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(msg);
  useEffect(() => cb(message), [message]);

  return [message, setMessage];
}
```

index.js

```js
function App() {
  
  const callback = (msg) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
  const [message, setMessage] = useData({
    content: "",
    type: "error"
  }, callback);

  

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMessage({
      content: "Hello message",
      type: "info"
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Alert Data
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're counting on `data` being updated the instant you call your `onClick` handler, but that won't be true until the next render. Instead, consider using a `useEffect` hook. In the following example, I've also created a stateful `open` variable to tell the modal when to be open.

```
function App() {
  const [data, action] = useData();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    action.setMessage("Hello message");
    action.setType("info");
    setOpen(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [open, data])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Alert Data
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```